# Visual Studio Online Continuous integration, Turn on/off customErrors Azure in different environments

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops

Three environments, where I want different settings:

- Production (Azure Web App) **CustomErrors ON**
- QA (Azure Web App) **CustomErrors OFF**
- Development (Visual Studio, run debug mode) **CustomErrors OFF**

In web.config.release, I can configure a transformation, that is used when Visual Studio Online deploys/releases to an environment.

But how do I make a different setting for customerrors in one environment?

I think it either has to be solved in the visual studio release definitionfor each environment, or as an application setting in the azure web app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Azure App Service Deploy task and enable the option XML Variable Substitution. This allows you to specify the variable values in your Release Definition and configure different values for each environment. On deployment, the task will then search and replace the values in your web.config with your specified values.

For more information see [Managing Configuration and App Settings for Multiple Environments in Your CD Pipeline](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/05/managing-configuration-app-settings-for-multiple-environments-in-your-cd-pipeline/)